# Manager Demanded that I put the Data Package I Provided Him into a Data Package

Tags: software-industry, united-states, manager

I recently had my duties reassigned so that I'm heading a new project for SSIS DTSX Packages.

The instructions I were provided were very vague and did not make much sense, but since I've been affiliated with the system for so long, I had a good sense of what direction my manager was going.

The project requires several DTSX packages to be created, with the first package having a deadline to prove that I'm capable of doing the project.

I created the DTSX package and provided it to my manager about a week prior to it being due for testing purposes or to see if there were any additional features that were desired since the instructions were so vague.

After about six days, my manager responded stating that I did not follow the original directions of creating a DTSX package and that I need to send him the project as a DTSX package. He threatened that if it was not completed prior to the deadline that there would be consequences.

After receiving the email, it's clear to me that my manager has not utilized anything within SSIS.

**How do I tell my manager that I've already sent him the DTSX package without being disciplined?**

Comment: **How** did you "provided it to my manager about a week prior"? Did you mention that? What did he say?

Comment: @nvoigt I provided it to him in a .zip file due to some of our security protocols on the exchange server.  I've yet to respond, but from previous experience telling my manager I provided something before it was due leads to discipline.

Comment: I have a feeling that there is more to your question than meets the eye. I would just forward the old email to my boss saying "hey, I sent this a week ago, let me know if you have any problems unpacking it". If you have been disciplined for doing this before, that seems very weird.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your manager is out to get you fired though.  He has taken an extremely hostile approach with you and given you a task that in his eyes you cannot succeed at.  You need to be watching for other signs that he wants to eliminate you and get out before he fires you for unsubstantiated cause.

Comment: First, why are you emailing SSIS packages? It should be in your source control and you should have provided him with the location to it there.  Next, Instead of emailing, I would have made a meeting appointment and presented it there where he could go through what you did and ask questions since the requirements were vague. You could also run it as a demo and show where the data was imported or exported or whatever it was through your unit tests (yes you should have unit tests for ALL SSIS packages).Then you would not have wasted six days.

Comment: @HLGEM Sadly, there is no source control at my company.  I've been advocating RedGate for over a year now, but my manager is reluctant to place any source control.

Comment: @BillLeeper I've been suspecting this too, many of the directions he has taken as of late has been to exclude me from tasks that directly impact my position so that he can discipline me at a later time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this stage, I would go to him in person, say you understand he has some questions about what you did and get the package from your email and open it on his desk if he has the right software installed or go to your desk if not.

Then walk through exactly what it does. Make sure to run the package after setting up any appropriate test files needed. Show through unit tests what the results were.

Make notes in writing of anything he thinks needs to be added. Follow up the meeting with an email stating that you are going to change these things per the meeting on  and the changes will be done by ...

Make sure to copy anyone he sent his angry email back to (if that was how he communicated his displeasure to you, that part wasn't clear). I would probably also casually mention that was a review of the package that was sent to him on such and such date and include that as an attachment. Then make the changes.  Now anyone else he forwarded this to is aware that you did send the package and you have documentation of the steps of the process and when they happened in case you need it later.

In the future, clarify vague requirements before starting to program. It saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

1) Walk over to his desk and show him how to open the code on his computer. (If you are not in the same location call him then suggest a screen share).

2) Be patient and answer all his questions.

3) Once he has none left, ask if there is anything else he would like\need, **point out that there is a week left!**.

4) Once done, tell him nicely but firmly "If you have question about my work, just ask, I will be more than happy to explain, **there are no need for threats**"

5) Followup up 2 days later asking if everything is OK.

Lastly he may be asking for the SSIS *Solution* rather than the SSIS *Package*, Who knows,regardless, *you need to remind him that you are on the same team and expect him to act like it*.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your manager and ask for a clear understanding of what he means by a DTSX package. Have him explain in his words, possibly showing you in the system, what he is talking about.  He may just be uninformed or may be getting terms mixed up.

If he can't do that, politely explain that you have given him a DTSX package.  If he is still adamant that that isn't right, then ask him to walk you through what he wants again.

Explain that he has had your work for 6 days with no comment and that you would like the courtesy of 6 additional days to correct whatever it is he is looking for.  Assuming that he is able to explain what he is looking for.

Lastly, if he is just totally incompetent and gets angry and demands you just do it, ask that he document his request in writing, with as much detail as possible.  This will help you in the event you need to escalate any challenge to his consequences.

You may need to go over his head, and soon, so as to protect yourself.  You may need to schedule a meeting with his boss explaining that he is asking for something you delivered, but that he doesn't understand the system enough to know that you delivered it.